# Java - stop GSON from creating an additional thread

Tags: java, multithreading, gson, backend

I'm writing some small code snippets in Java to be run on a mobile application backend server. The server I'm using has a limit of one thread, so the code I write needs to basically be synchronous and single threaded.

I'm using gson to parse JSON which I retrieve from a third party API, some example code is below:

```
public class JSONWorker {

    public double getJSONFromURL(String sURL){
        JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(); //from gson
        JsonElement root = null;

        // Connect to the URL using java's native library
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(sURL);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        URLConnection request = null;
        try {
            request = url.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            request.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject(); 
        String price = rootobj.get("lastPrice").getAsString(); 
        return Double.parseDouble(price);

    }
}
```

The error which is being returned states that I don't have permission to create an additional thread and points to this particular line as the problem:

```
root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent()));
```

Is it correct that the JSON parser in gson should create an additional thread? 
Could this be something to do with the fact it's running on a remote server?
Is there a way to force gson or specifically the parser to be synchronous/single threaded?

EDIT: Full error output

```
[ERROR] You have no permission to create thread in CodeRunner secure group.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.backendless.coderunner.runtime.task.TimerInvocationTask.runImpl(TimerInvocationTask.java:52)
    at com.backendless.coderunner.runtime.executor.ExtendedRunnable.run(ExtendedRunnable.java:39)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: You have no permission to create thread in CodeRunner secure group.
    at com.backendless.coderunner.runtime.security.CodeRunnerSecurityManager.checkAccess(CodeRunnerSecurityManager.java:48)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.checkAccess(ThreadGroup.java:315)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.getParent(ThreadGroup.java:167)
    at sun.net.www.http.KeepAliveCache$1.run(KeepAliveCache.java:102)
    at sun.net.www.http.KeepAliveCache$1.run(KeepAliveCache.java:96)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.http.KeepAliveCache.put(KeepAliveCache.java:95)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.putInKeepAliveCache(HttpsClient.java:659)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.finished(HttpClient.java:395)
    at sun.net.www.http.KeepAliveStream.close(KeepAliveStream.java:97)
    at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.justRead(MeteredStream.java:93)
    at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(MeteredStream.java:135)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3393)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.fillBuffer(JsonReader.java:1295)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextNonWhitespace(JsonReader.java:1333)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.consumeNonExecutePrefix(JsonReader.java:1576)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:534)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:425)
    at com.google.gson.internal.Streams.parse(Streams.java:46)
    at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:84)
    at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:59)
    at com.myApp.timers.PriceGetterTimer.execute(PriceGetterTimer.java:100)
    ... 6 common frames omitted
```

Cheers,
Mitch

Comment: Are you defining the `KeepAliveStream` anywhere? Check to see what type of strean is being returned from `request.getContent()`. Gson isn't doing anything odd, it's the streams themselves which are starting threads.

Comment: @JohnVint I'm not defining it myself, I believe it's part of the backend server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thread is created by built-in `KeepAliveCache`.

You can either specify request header `Connection` with value of `Close` or set system property `http.keepAlive` to value `false` like this (before you actually open connection):

```
System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
```

More information can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-keepalive.html)

Comment: many thanks. This has fixed it for me. For everyones references, adding the line System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false"); was not enough to stop the behaviour. But request.addRequestProperty("Connection","close"); before calling request.connect did the job. Thanks again! :D

Answer (score 1):

It seems likely that it is not `gson` that is the problem here but the `request.getContent()`.

In many cases, transforming a data stream of some sort into an `InputStream` requires a thread of it's own. Perhaps the data is streaming in from a website and being buffered by the web communications layer. Converting it to a stream on-the-fly could be most efficiently implemented using a thread.

Comment: Yes I was thinking it may be the request itself, but the error output points to the gson parser line of code in particular, I will add the full error to my question